# How to save a spark dataframe to csv on HDFS?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

Spark version: 1.6.1, I use pyspark API.

DataFrame: df, which has two colume.

I have tried:

```
1: df.write.format('csv').save("hdfs://path/bdt_sum_vol.csv")
2: df.write.save('hdfs://path/bdt_sum_vol.csv', format='csv', mode='append')
3: df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').save('hdfs://path/')
4: df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('hdfs://path/df.csv')

(All above didn't work, Failed to find data source)
```

or:

```
def toCSVLine(data):
    return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

lines = df.rdd.map(toCSVLine)
lines.saveAsTextFile('hdfs://path/df.csv')  

(Permission denied)
```

Q:

1, How to solve "Failed to find data source"?

2, I used sudo to make the dictionary "/path" on hdfs, if I turn the dataframe to rdd, how to write the rdd to csv on hdfs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which version of databricks are you running : -`-packages com.databricks...`?

Comment: seems like a user permission issue if you can use `hadoop` on the same server do this, `hadoop chown user:user /path` where user is the one with which you are running your spark code.

Comment: 1. Try paths without "hdfs:/"
2. lines.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile('/pyth/df.csv')

Also check if you have r/w permission on hdfs

Comment: I sovled this problem. 1, gained access. 2, turn each row of rdd into string and use    `saveAsTextFile()` to save the result into part-***. Or, 3, if I use 
    `save()`, I should submit application like    `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0  /path`,  so I can save it! Thank you all !

Comment: instead of 'hdfs://path/df.csv'   try   'file:///path/df.csv'

Answer (score 2):

You could try to change ".save" to ".csv":

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').option('header','true').csv('hdfs://path/df.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

If `hdfs://yourpath/` doesn't work

Try this, In my case it worked:
`df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').save("/user/user_name/file_name")`

So technically we are using a single reducer if there are multiple partitions by default for this data frame. And you will get one CSV in your hdfs location.

Comment: +1
This does however, write the csv out as a 'folder', and the actual csv inside it has a really wierd name.